# Drools not working as advertised in expert documentation

Tags: drools

I have two very simple rules

```
rule "Volume Validation"
    salience 10
when 

    avs : AvailabilityStatusAndDiscountDisplay( quantity > 1000 || quantity < 0) 

then    

    avs.setAvailable(false);        
    avs.setDiscountRateUnavailableMessage("Unavailable Quanitity");
end 

rule "Discount Rate Calculation -1"

salience 9

when 

     AvailabilityStatusAndDiscountDisplay( productType == "111",calculated==false, available == true, quantity >= 50) 

     avs:   AvailabilityStatusAndDiscountDisplay()
then    

    avs.setDiscountRate("0.65");
    avs.setCalculated(true);

end
```

but when the quantity is 5000 and available is set to false by the first rule. The second "rule" can't see that change and proceeds with evaluation.
Even though,    https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_SOA_Platform/5/html/JBoss_Rules_5_Reference_Guide/chap-examples.html#id18463514 advertises that the object changed in the working memory will be seen by the next rule in the sequence.

Edit. After very much appreciated help from @alicox

```
rule "Volume Validation"
salience 10
no-loop true
when 

avs : AvailabilityStatusAndDiscountDisplay( quantity > 1000 || quantity < 0) 

then    

avs.setAvailable(false);        
avs.setDiscountRateUnavailableMessage("Unavailable Quanitity");
update(avs);
end 

rule "Discount Rate Calculation -1"

salience 9

when 

AvailabilityStatusAndDiscountDisplay( productType == "111",calculated==false,   available == true, quantity >= 50) 

avs:   AvailabilityStatusAndDiscountDisplay()
then    

avs.setDiscountRate("0.65");
avs.setCalculated(true);

end
```

This works.

alicox also made a suggestion to create a bread crumbs through an insert method if I understood correctly like this

```
then 
     insert (blah = true) //so as not to fire new rule 
    end 
//new rule 
when 
     blah == false
```

not sure though what kind of object has to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call update or modify on avs after changing its properties for it to be re-evaluated in LHS part.

Also in your second rule LHS can be shortened to the following:

```
avs: AvailabilityStatusAndDiscountDisplay( productType == "111",
           calculated==false, available == true, quantity >= 50)
```

Calling update or modify on a fact will cause the rules that references to that rule in their LHS part to be fired again. You have several options if this is not the expected behaviour

1) use no-loop, this will prevent updates done in a rule, trigger itself

2) use finer grained facts.

3) Insert breadcrumb facts into session after update, and check their existence in LHS. First define a fact type in your model named Breadcrumb and has a string attribute "name", Then use as follws.

```
when
  not Breadcrumb(name == "calculationXXXDone")
  ....
then
  ...
  //do some work
  ...
  bc = new Breadcrumb()
  bc.name = "calculationXXXDone"
  insert(bc)
```

Comment: alikox, after I posted this question I kept trying new things. And I did try to use modify and update because I understand that you if you don't use MVEL style you need to tell the working memory to update but
        avs.setAvailable(false);  
 avs.setDiscountRateUnavailableMessage("Unav Quanitity");
 modify(avs);
and I get
Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='Volume Validation']
 com/alex/qBPP/drools/domain/Rule_Volume_Validation_0.java (13:639) : The method modify(AvailabilityStatusAndDiscountDisplay) is undefined for the type Rule_Volume_Validation_0
and with update (avs) infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, right before you updated, I just got it working with no-loop.
I understand that modify is probably only to be used when we use mvel.
I used insert and no-loop = true to keep from re-evaluating the same rule. It also seems from the HelloWorld example from the doc. that in case of the modify you don't need to do no-loop.

Comment: When you mention bread-crumbs I'm assuming it something like
    then
      insert (blah = true) //so as not to fire new rule
    end
    //new rule
    when
       blah == false 
    then
If you could give me an actual example it would be fantastic because I know a lot of people are probably struggling with the same time of question.